# how to search on the first occurence of a string using regex JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, regex

I have an html code which contain so many SPANs.

I want to search for a specific string and replace it with "X" char. The problem is that in some cases a word is divided among many spans not just one.

For example, in the code below, I'm searching for the word "Alger", but it's written in three spans. So how should I do this ?

```html
<p>
  <meta charset=utf-8>Declaration-sur-lhonneur MOHAMED
</p>
<p>
  <span class="Policepardfaut">A</span>
  <span>lger</span>
  <span class="Policepardfaut">Le</span>
  <span>07/05</span>
  <span>2018</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Please show us what you tried, e.g. the code you wrote and don't forget to include error messages (if there are any).

Comment: Please update the snippet I made with the code you tried

Comment: Also you `<meta charset=utf-8>` belongs in the head, not in the middle of a p

Comment: for the moment i couldn't find out how to start

Comment: the html code is way more complicated then it looks , it's generated based on a docx file

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start

```js
let arr = []
document.querySelectorAll("span").forEach(span => arr.push(span.textContent))
console.log("Alger found?",arr.join("").indexOf("Alger")>=0)
```

```html
<p>
  <meta charset=utf-8>Declaration-sur-lhonneur MOHAMED
</p>
<p>
  <span class="Policepardfaut">A</span>
  <span>lger</span>
  <span class="Policepardfaut">Le</span>
  <span>07/05</span>
  <span>2018</span>
</p>
```

Comment: it can only help teling if the element do exist or not